# WebSockets - Problems with server not fulfilling wss request. What could be wrong?

Tags: node.js, nginx, websocket

I have an application written in node.js thats working thru normal ws. I am trying to make it work with wss, but it just not happening. I need wss because chrome will not allow me to use camera/microphone on unsecure connection.

I got certificate, HTTPS is working.

I also included this in my node.js server app:

```
// Minimal amount of secure websocket server
var fs = require('fs');

// read ssl certificate
var privateKey = fs.readFileSync('ssl-cert/privkey.pem', 'utf8');
var certificate = fs.readFileSync('ssl-cert/fullchain.pem', 'utf8');

var credentials = { key: privateKey, cert: certificate };
var https = require('https');

//pass in your credentials to create an https server
var httpsServer = https.createServer(credentials);
httpsServer.listen(9090);

var WebSocketServer = require('ws').Server;
```

I also edited nginx.conf:

```
tcp {
    upstream websockets {
        ## webbit websocket server in background
        server 89.221.222.68:9090;

        check interval=3000 rise=2 fall=5 timeout=1000;
    }   

    server {
        server_name _;
        listen 9090;

        ssl on;
        proxy_ssl_certificate     /ssl-cert/fullchain.pem;
        proxy_ssl_certificate_key /ssl-cert/privkey.pem;

        timeout 43200000;
        websocket_connect_timeout 43200000;
        proxy_connect_timeout 43200000;

        so_keepalive on;
        tcp_nodelay on;

        websocket_pass websockets;
        websocket_buffer 1k;
    }
}
```

I also tried setting ProxyPass in apache2 config, but nothing seems to work.

I do not know where is the problem and mi limited linux experience is not helping me there.

**So my question:**
How you can setup wss from scratch? I have node.js app running at server.com/9090 which I need to communicate with from the client side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Forever plugin wasnt working and server was not running. Its working now.